# Change directive attribute without reloading in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I use angular-ui carousel ,and my directive now looks like this

```
<ui-carousel 
    slides-to-show="calculateGamesCount"
    slides-to-scroll="calculateGamesCount"> 
      ... 
</ui-carousel>
```

Directive scope:

```
show: '=slidesToShow',
scroll: '=slidesToScroll',
```

After resize i should change "calculateGamesCount" value .
Now I do it with directive reload , but its not good way .

**How I can change attribute value without directives reload ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share more of the code from your directive.

Comment: @DanielWarke i use this directive , value changes from another cantroller with simple resize event .
https://github.com/mihnsen/ui-carousel

Comment: it looks like it's a 2-way bound variable in the directive. Have you tried just updating calculateGamesCount to a new value? You need to include your controller code in the question

Comment: @Ero calculates and change attrs works well , but its deosnt change anythink in carousel directive